# Export dataframe as pdf using grid.table throws error

Tags: r

I'm trying to export several data frames as pdf using grid.table but I get an error. My data frame is like this

```
GAME                 WEIGHT       RECO         LEAGUE    IDGAME    TEST

Nice/Reims            1.8        Nice          Ligue 1   RG23       1
St Etienne/Guingamp   1.8        St Etienne    Ligue 1   RG22       0
Paris SG/Caen         1.8        Paris SG      Ligue 1   RG31       1
```

So this table is a mix of different class

```
>sapply(`WKPDAY12018/2019`, class)
       GAME      WEIGHT        RECO      LEAGUE      IDGAME 
   "character"   "numeric"  "character" "character"  "list"
```

I don't know if this is related to the export issue I'm having but when I tried with a full numeric data frame it worked.

So I'm trying this so far :

```
pdf("test.pdf",height = 11, width =  8.5)
grid.table(`WKPDAY12018/2019`)
dev.off()
```

And I get this error :

```
> grid.table(`WKPDAY12018/2019`)
Error in (function (label, parse = FALSE, col = "black", fontsize = 12,  : 
  unused arguments (label.GAME = dots[[5]][[1]], label.WEIGHT = dots[[6]][[1]], label.RECO = dots[[7]][[1]], label.LEAGUE = dots[[8]][[1]], label.IDGAME = dots[[9]][[1]])
> dev.off()
```

Comment: Why are IDGAME of type list?

Comment: Well I don't really know, in the dataframe from which i've subset it was in character

Comment: You can try to convert it to character using `as.character() `

Comment: It's working thank you. Do you know what may cause a column to classify as list ? Because when I initialized my dataframe, I had specified IDGAME = character ()

Comment: Hmm, sorry no idea. How do you fill the data frame?

Comment: Just found out. I was using [ , ] to fill this column. And changing this to double [[ , ]] kept the character format.